# Diagonalizable Matrices and calculating $A^5$

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether $A$ is diagonalizable and if it is, calculate $A^5$.

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
   3   & -1  &  -1 \\
   -12 &  0  &  5  \\
   4   & -2  &  -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So I calculated the eigenvalues by factoring and got $(\lambda -2)(1- \lambda ^2)=0 $ so $\lambda = -1,1,2$.  So I tried to calculate the eigenvectors.

For $\lambda = 1$ I plugged in the eigenvalue to get 
$$
A- \lambda I=
\begin{bmatrix}
   2   & -1  &  -1 \\
   -12 & -1  &  5  \\
   4   & -2  &  -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which could be row reduced to the identity matrix, so I got an eigenvector of 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Using the same process, for the eigenvalue of $\lambda = -1$, I got an eigenvector of 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   2\\
   2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and for an eigenvalue of $\lambda = 2 $ I got an eigenvector of 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   -1 \\
    1 \\
   -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So to figure out $A^5$ I am supposed to use the fact that to diagonalize the matrix, I use $S^{-1}AS=D$ where D is the diagonalized matrix.  and I am supposed to use the fact that $SD^5S^{-1}=A^5$

So
$$S=
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -1 & 1 \\
   0 &  1 & 2 \\
   0 & -2 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
D=
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However, my problem is that I know the eigenvector for $\lambda = 1 $ is wrong and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  Thank you for anyone that helps.

Comment: $A - I$ cannot be reduced to the identity.  Go through that row reduction again.

Comment: Also, if $A - \lambda I$ can be row-reduced to the identity, then $\lambda$ is **not** an eigenvalue.

Comment: The zero vector is by definition never an eigenvector.

Comment: don't  you see that the third row $A - I$ is twice that of the first row of $A - I.$ that alone tells you $(2, 0, -1)^T$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1.$

Comment: i made a mistake in my earlier comment. $(2, 0, -1)^T$ is in the left null space. the vector $(3, -1, 7)$ is in the (right)null space. apologies.

Comment: @abel, $v=(3,-1,7)$ certainly does not satisfy $(A-I)v=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, i guess i don't know how to find the null space of $A - I.$  it will be helpful if you post the answer with your snide remark.

Comment: @abel, my apologies, arithmetical error on my part.